# How to draw existing graphics to a BufferedImage - Java

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I a have a JPanel where I have drawn some lines. Now I want to pass those graphics as a BufferedImage to another class, but I don't know how. I know the way to get the graphic2D object of a BufferedImage and draw on it, but how to do the reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `BufferedImage` of the panel.

Check out the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class. It allows you to create an Image of any Swing component.